# Drawing Lines in Java with a loop

Tags: java, lines

I need help drawing lines in Java. I have written the code for one corner with 15 lines. But I am having trouble figuring out how to draw these 15 lines again in each of the 4 corners at the same time. Can anyone show me how to mirror my current code in each of the 4 corners?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawOneSetOfLines extends JPanel
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DrawOneSetOfLines panel = new DrawOneSetOfLines();

   JFrame application = new JFrame();


    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    application.add(panel); 
    application.setSize(250, 250); 
    application.setVisible(true); 
} 

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    super.paintComponent(g);

    int linesToDraw = 15;
    int width = getWidth(); 
    int height = getHeight(); 
    int number, y, x, dy, dx;
      x = 0;
      y = height;
      number = 15;
      dx = width / number;
      dy = height / number;
      for( int i = 1; i < number; i++ )
      {
        x += dx;
        y -= dy;
        g.drawLine( 0, 0, y, x );


} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Please make an attempt before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 0;
y = height;
```

This will start at the far left, in the bottom corner. It's simply a case of changing these values. For example:

```
x = width; // Far right
y = 0; // Top of the component.
```

Ergo, this will start in the top right of the component.